# How can I optimize Jquery code to display multiple file uploads?

Tags: jquery, forms, file-upload, hide

I am building a file upload partial view to be shared among a few different pages. We have a maximum of 5 files right now, but I'd rather have each maximum be set by the page using it through ViewBag or something simple like that. I currently have five different functions to clear and hide inputs as a "remove" button is clicked, and when the removes are clicked out of order, the "Add Another File" link does not behave as I would hope. It readds an input, but wherever the "highest" removed input was and does not clear when the limit is reached again until the user tries to add a sixth. Here's my code, any suggestions to clear up these annoyances would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.upload2').hide();
    $('.upload3').hide();
    $('.upload4').hide();
    $('.upload5').hide();

    $('.showNext').click(function () {
        if (!$('.upload2').is(':visible')){
            $('.upload2').show();
        }
        else if (!$('.upload3').is(':visible')) {
            $('.upload3').show();
        }
        else if (!$('.upload4').is(':visible')) {
            $('.upload4').show();
        }
        else if (!$('.upload5').is(':visible')) {
            $('.upload5').show();
            $('.showNext').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('.showNext').hide();
        }

    });
});

function upload2Clear() {
    $('.upload2').hide('slow');
    $('.FileUpload2').val('');
    $('.DescriptionUpload2').val('');
    $('.showNext').show();
}

function upload3Clear() {
    $('.upload3').hide('slow');
    $('.FileUpload3').val('');
    $('.DescriptionUpload3').val('');
    $('.showNext').show();
}

function upload4Clear() {
    $('.upload4').hide('slow');
    $('.FileUpload4').val('');
    $('.DescriptionUpload4').val('');
    $('.showNext').show();
}

function upload5Clear() {
    $('.upload5').hide('slow');
    $('.FileUpload5').val('');
    $('.DescriptionUpload5').val('');
    $('.showNext').show();
}
```

```
<h4>Upload a File</h4>


<div class="showNext" style="position:absolute; left:33%;"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Add Another File</a></div><br />
<div style="position:absolute; left:33%;"><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></div>

<div class="upload1"><input type="file" name="FileUpload1" /><br />
    <label>Description:<br /><input type="text" name="DescriptionUpload1" size="50" maxlength="200" /></label>
</div>
<div class="upload2"><input type="file" name="FileUpload2" class="FileUpload2" />&nbsp;
    <img src="~/Images/remove.png" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="upload2Clear();"/><br />
    <label>Description:<br /><input type="text" name="DescriptionUpload2" class="DescriptionUpload2" size="50" maxlength="200" /></label>
</div>
<div class="upload3"><input type="file" name="FileUpload3" class="FileUpload3" />&nbsp;
    <img src="~/Images/remove.png" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="upload3Clear();"/><br />
    <label>Description:<br /><input type="text" name="DescriptionUpload3" class="DescriptionUpload3" size="50" maxlength="200" /></label>
</div>
<div class="upload4"><input type="file" name="FileUpload4" class="FileUpload4" />&nbsp;
    <img src="~/Images/remove.png" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="upload4Clear();"/><br />
    <label>Description:<br /><input type="text" name="DescriptionUpload4" size="50" maxlength="200" /></label>
</div>
<div class="upload5"><input type="file" name="FileUpload5" class="FileUpload5" />&nbsp;
    <img src="~/Images/remove.png" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="upload5Clear();"/><br />
    <label>Description:<br /><input type="text" name="DescriptionUpload5" class="DescriptionUpload5" size="50" maxlength="200" /></label>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you use jquery library like `uploadify` or some other?

Comment: Honestly, inexperience with jquery and not knowing something like that exists. Any helpful links you think are the preferred resource? @MuhammadHaseebKhan

Comment: `uploadify.com` is best for multiple uploads plus it has everything which you want